# Coulomb interaction between two electrons is repulsive. So how can the potential term in simplified Hubbard model favour localisation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

In Quantum Field Theory For The Gifted Amateur it says that Hubbard model is interplay between kinetic energy term which favours delocalization and potential energy favours localisation. Seems to contradict with the fact that electrons repel. I would like to know what I am missing.

Comment: The potential energy is not the inter-particle interaction; rather, it is (simply speaking, with some stuff swept under the rug) the external potential in which the electrons sit, which is a periodic potential that localizes the electrons to ionic cores in the material.

Comment: @march Thanks. To clarify do you mean to say the potential energy of lattice electron interaction that is otherwise constant as long as electrons are inside lattice. But it prevents electrons from exiting lattice hence localizing it inside the lattice.

Comment: @march According to the book, the "potential energy" does mean the interparticle interaction.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why the potential in the Hubbard model favors localization is exactly given by your first statement; namely

> Coulomb interaction between two electrons is repulsive.

This means the potential energy between two electrons are positive and putting two electrons in the same site will cost (increase) energy. Therefore, this potential will "motivate" an electron to prefer spending most of its time alone in a site (i.e. localization condition), rather than to hop to different sites and meet another electron. The preference of an electron to hop also depends on the strength of kinetic energy relative to the potential (Hubbard) U. This localization condition is more apparent when the system being considered is half-filled.